# Problem applying transformation on tiff images using wand

Tags: python, wand, magickwand

I am using wand package to convert a pdf file to tif file. I called Image. transform function to resize the image. Below is the code snippet

```py
with Image(filename='sample.pdf') as img:
    img.format='TIF'
    img.transform('50%')
    img.save(filename='sample.tif')
```

the code throw an `xception:wand.exceptions.OptionError: invalide geometry ' @ error/geometry.c/ParseRegionGeometry/1524`
I tried `transform('800x1100')`. it did not work either

Answer (score 0):

I believe the argument format for `Image.transform()` is the following...

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='sample.pdf') as img:
    img.transform(resize='50%')
    img.save(filename='sample.tif')
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried that too. It didn't work either.